# Eclipse messing up excluded filter?

Tags: eclipse, maven, resources

Eclipse is setting constantly excluded filter in build path config to **, which causes resources to be excluded from deployment. Anyone aware of this issue, and how this can be prevented? Any thoughts?

Comment: My first thought is that your Maven build should have nothing to do with your IDE - expecially if something like Eclipse is in usage (while my Maven builds works fine - Eclipse states there are tousands of classes missing in ITs classpath... i dont care about the classpath of Eclipse - i care about compile, runtime, provided, etc. classpaths). I am however not sure if you use Maven at all ... If so: Are you only compiling your component and let eclipse pack it to its final form - why not have Maven pack it? If no: remove the Maven label from your question.

Comment: I'm using maven and Eclipse, both, so I run solution in Eclipse through tomcat server, but I can also package projects from maven in console, both should work, but Eclipse is messing up this settings not sure why it's doing it.

Comment: O.k. i am sorry i dont have a tested solution for you in this case - i will however add a answer with two things i would try next.

Answer (score 0):

How i said in the comments of your question i did not verify any of both approaches and i only think/hope they could lead to a solution rather than i know it exactly.

**First approach:**

Since you handle the entire process of compilation and packaging via Maven i assume you collect required ressources with Maven only (and that if you filter out certain ressources you would do that with Maven only). In that case i would try to disable all of the eclipse filters to be included into the build path - which i would expect as the behaviour if you disable this option:

[image: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Building -> disable Option "Enable use of exclusion patterns in source folders"]

(i once experienced eclipse added a "*"Filter to my `Type Filters` hence i wasnt able to find anything on typesearch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> anymore - so my hope is a similar behaviour when it comes to your filter-all-resources filter"

**Second approach**

Actually i think that this approach will only affect the view rather than the build/ deployment process but hey its eclipse - you just never know so i guess its worth a try:

[image: In the view <code>Project Explorer</code> select the small down-pointing arrow and select the option <code>Customize View...</code>]

In the following screen you should see any filters known by eclipse - i assume you will see the *.* Filter there as well and be able to unselect it:

[image: Unselect your filter in the <code>Filters</code> tab]

I guess its worth a try - good luck ;)

Comment: yes definitely maven is messing up include/exclude filters, not sure there is setup in maven pom.xml to enable disable filtering will try with option to see what happens, when I disable exclusion of resources eclipse gives me errors.